# Why does a hole have greater energy than valence electrons?

Tags: material-science

According to the following diagram (this is for a p-type semiconductor) :
[image]

The acceptor level - which is the hole, has a higher energy than the valence electrons as it is above the valence band. But why does the hole have greater energy than the valence electrons? Shouldn't it have the same energy as an electron as it is simply the broken bond that an electron leaves behind (when the electron gets promoted)?

The text I was studying from also stated that a hole is a place where an electron can be promoted to, but why and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holes energy is measured down from valence band top because of their positive charge.

Remember that in real world there are no holes. This is quasi-particle  introduced in order to describe movement of valence electrons, which is very hard due to high concentration of them. Huge amount of valence electrons is thus replaced by moderate amount of holes.

My advice is to read classic solid state books, for example, *Kittel* or (and) *Aschcroft and Mermin*, they step-by-step explain everything from the origins.

P.S. Semiconductor questions should go to electrical engineering.

Comment: Thank you, and my bad I'm learning about this in my material science course - so I used the material science tag.

Comment: semiconductor theory qualifies as Physics too.